# UIActivityViewController share a video on WhatsApp

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have look around a lot but didn't find a solution to my problem.

I am displaying videos in a tableviewcell like this

```
        if let videoUrlString = post?.videoUrl, let videoUrl = URL(string: videoUrlString) {

        self.volumenView.isHidden = false
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer?.frame = postImageView.frame
        playerLayer?.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        playerLayer?.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / post!.ratio!
        self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
        self.volumenView.layer.zPosition = 1
        player?.play()
        player?.isMuted = isMuted

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem)

    }
```

this works perfectly fine.
Now I want the user to be able to share the video on WhatsApp.
I ve made it work text post and image post which work fine but wasn't able to make it run with videos.

this is how I currently send the notification

```
  let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: (post?.videoUrl)!)

        let data:[String: NSURL] = ["video": videoURL]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "shareCalled"), object: nil, userInfo: data)
```

this works so far that the chat partner receives a link to where the video is stored in firebase and by clicking that link he can see the video.
This works but its not elegant, I would like to send the video as one and not as a link where the user has to suspiciously click on.

Any idea?

**Edit: code where I share the post (notice: text and image work fine, video just sends the url but not a video as one**

```
    @objc func shareCalled(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let data = notification.userInfo?["image"] as? UIImage {
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [data], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList,UIActivityType.openInIBooks, UIActivityType.openInIBooks]
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    if let data = notification.userInfo?["caption"] as? String {
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [data], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList,UIActivityType.openInIBooks, UIActivityType.openInIBooks]
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    if let data = notification.userInfo?["video"] as? URL {
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [data], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList,UIActivityType.openInIBooks, UIActivityType.openInIBooks]
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to use the `UIActivityViewController`?

Comment: I added the code where I share the post, notice: image and text work fine

Comment: did you try to download the video as data and share it?

Comment: no not yet as I don't know how I cloud do that :/